# node.js ограничение доступа по ip

Tags: node.js, ip

Как в node.js ограничить доступ по ip?

Необходимо разрешить доступ к сайту только для нескольких айпи. А вот как это сделать - не могу нигде найти.

*Заранее спасибо всем откликнувшимся!*

Comment: Так а проблема в чем? Вы не знаете как ip в node.js вычислить что-ли?

Comment: @AlexWindHope, мой хрустальный шар говорит "Да". )

Comment: мои познания в ноде весьма поверхностны. понимания логики работы практически нет. вся инфа вырвана кусками из западных мануалов. инфы по данному вопросу я не нашел. допустим, как определить айпи я могу найти, а вот куда прописать его проверку, и что делать в случае совпадения/несовпадения - не понятно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если правильно понял, то как-то так (не тестировал)

```
var http = require('http');
function createHttpServerForIps( ips, isProxy, onAllowed, onNotAllowed ) {
  return http.createServer(function( request, response ) {

    function getIp() {
      return isProxy
      ? request.headers['x-forwarded-for'] ||
      : request.connection.remoteAddress;
    }

    function ipAllowed( ip ) {
      var allowed = false;
      for( var i=0; i<ips.length; ++i ) {
        if( ip === ips[i] ) {
          allowed = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      return allowed;
    }

    ipAllowed( getIp() )
    ? onAllowed( request, response )
    : onNotAllowed( request, response );
  });
}

var isProxy = false;
createHttpServerForIps([
    '123.123.123.133',
    '344.344.344.344'
  ], isProxy,
  function( request, response ) {
    // ... allowed
  },
  function( request, response ) {
    // ... not allowed
  }
).listen(8000);
```

В случае совпадения (первый callback) отрабатывает ваша логика, в случае ошибки (второй callback) можете как 403 отдавать, так и тупо обрывать соединение, решать вам.

Comment: Спасибо, очень достойный ответ! Теперь главное чтобы ф-ция getIp() правильно отдавала IP. чуть позже протестирую. Благодарю!

Comment: @Vitalii Maslianok - можете не тестировать ( выпейте чашечку кофе вместо этого :) ), все работает, независимо от того, есть ли nginx proxy или нет

Comment: .

    function getIp() {
      return request.headers['x-forwarded-for'] ||
             request.connection.remoteAddress;
    }

Это наиглупейший способ ограничения доступа по ip, который я когда-либо видел.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, продолжение мысли будет?

Comment: Я решил, что это очевидно. Но раз это не так, то повторюсь:

[`X-Forwarded-For`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For) - это обычный [HTTP-заголовок](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) в котором пользователь может передавать совершенно произвольные данные. 

Кроме того, этот заголовок может содержать строку с цепью ip прокси, разделенные запятой, где первым будет ip из внутренней подсети, например 192.168.0.1 или даже 127.0.0.1

Comment: Т.е., это все равно, что разрешить куда-либо доступ ограниченному кругу лиц строго по паспорту, но при этом считать паспортом любую туалетную бумагу с ФИО и надписью "Паспорт".

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, вы можете предложить другие варианты? (кроме как дополнительную обработку x-forwarded-for).

Вообще, насколько мне известно, nginx перезаписывает пользовательские заголовки. Но, вообще, да, надо было написать что-то типа:

     function getIp() {
       return isProxy
       ? request.headers['x-forwarded-for']
       : request.connection.remoteAddress 
     }

Fixed

Comment: @AlexWindHope,

> Вообще, насколько мне известно, nginx перезаписывает пользовательские заголовки.

Может переписывать и переписывает - это разные вещи. Собственно, nginx делает только то, что ему указано делать в настройках. Если там будет просто:

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;

То он передаст запрос один в один без изменений.

По-правильному, при проксировании нужно выставить как-ой либо кастомный заголовок, к примеру:

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

А в nodejs проверять, если `remoteAddress == nginxAddress`, то берем ip из заголовка `X-Real-IP`.

Comment: "А в nodejs проверять, если remoteAddress == nginxAddress" what???

Я, безусловно, все прекрасно понимаю, но, если на то пошло, давайте на вопросы книги писать, о nginx, о кастомных заголовках, о том как нужно настраивать прокси ( ...о смысле бытия... ).

Если человек не шарит в настройке nginx, то он дернет конфиг из сети, там переопределение заголовка есть, а если шарит и без нас разберется, не?

Answer (score 2):

Добыли IP (`req.connection.remoteAddress`), сравнили со списком, если нельзя пускать - кинули клиенту в ответ согласно RFC статус `403 Forbidden`.

Comment: @Nofate - если node.js работает за nginx proxy, то remoteAddress всегда будет '127.0.0.1' :)

Comment: хм, да не подумал.

Comment: Если nginx крутится на том же сервере, что и node.js, то проверка будет:

    if (request.connection.remoteAddress == '127.0.0.1') {
        return request.headers['x-real-ip'];
    }
    return request.connection.remoteAddress;

Если на другом сервере, то вместо 127.0.0.1 будет адрес этого сервера, соответственно.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, я просто не понял - чем адрес сервера лучше флага isProxy?

Comment: > Если человек не шарит в настройке nginx, то он дернет конфиг из сети

Копипаст без понимания работы конфига - это еще хуже. Кроме того, нигде в сети не встречал записи:

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

Обычно пишется:

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

А это принципиально ничего не меняет.

> я просто не понял - чем адрес сервера лучше флага isProxy?

Принципиально - ни чем. Флаг, конечно же тоже сойдет.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, @Ilya Pirogov, спасибо за познавательную дискуссию.